# Locking to modify static value-type member. Is it necessary?

Tags: multithreading, locking, static-members

I have a CacheHelper class to facilitate interaction with the cache. I want to use a static int field to specify my cache timeout. The field is initially set to a const default value but I want to provide a way for the application to change the default timeout value.

Do you need to lock when modifying a static value type? Is the lock in the setter necessary? Are there any other problems you can see here? Sorry, I'm still pretty dumb when it comes to multithreading.

Thanks.

```
public static class CacheHelper
{
    private static object _SyncRoot;
    private static int _TimeoutInMinutes = CacheDefaults.TimeoutInMinutes; 

    public static int TimeoutInMinutes
    {
        get
        {
            return _TimeoutInMinutes;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_SyncRoot)
            {
                if (_TimeoutInMinutes != value)
                {
                    _TimeoutInMinutes = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Insert(string key, Object data)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null && data != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, data, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CacheHelper.TimeoutInMinutes));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a volatile variable instead... but you need *something*, otherwise it's possible that a value written by one thread would never be seen by another.

Note that for "larger" types such as `double` or `long` you really *should* use a lock or the `Interlocked` class, as modifications to those values may not be atomic.

Comment: Is it okay to combine the use of volatile and a lock? The timeout value is going to be read from a lot but written to rarely (if ever, other than on application startup by code in Global.asax).

Comment: @whatispunk: Well, it won't do any harm... but it won't help much either. Why would you use both? Volatile is enough for the `int` case...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm just trying to wrap my head around what all of this means. There seem to be varying opinions about the use of volatile and I don't even understand most of the lingo behind it, i.e. multiple CPUs and ordering of instructions, etc. Definitely gotta take some time to read about multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to lock here if the client of CacheHelper does somthing like

```
CacheHelper.TimeoutInMinutes = input.Value;
```

Since it doesn't rely on the previous value.

If your client does something like

```
CacheHelper.TimeoutInMinutes += input.Value;
```

Then you'll need to do some locking

.